# update label.text multiple times during button click event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to show the processing of the code,which runs on button click event.
Please help.
My code is something like below.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some stuff

        //Show the message that the application is processing

        lblCaption.Text = "Processing...updating label data";


        //Do more stuff

        lblCaption.Text = "Processing...creating label files.";


       //More stuff that will take some time

        lblCaption.Text = "Processing...updating label counts.";


        //More stuff

        lblCaption.Text = "Processing...completed.";

    }
```

Comment: Its not simple as that... and you can not do that....

Comment: This article may help you implementing yours, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642773/AJAX-Progress-Bar

Comment: Create a string and add your informati on step by step to keep the informations ? Here you'll only see the last message when the tasks will be finished

Comment: yes.I can see only the last message i.e Processing...completed.

Comment: Can any one tell me the solution for this?Please Help...